# Databricks show all columns in table

Tags: sql, databricks

I have a table with a lot of columns... the result is getting truncated and I cannot scroll to the right.

How can I show all columns using SQL?

I have tried:

```
%sql SHOW COLUMNS IN 

%sql  DESCRIBE EXTENDED
```

amongst others.

Comment: You just need to see the column names, or rather, are you also trying to see contents from a query result? `%sql show columns in database.tablename` will return the column names.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't very clear.  I need each column name in a table... I don't need the data. So in DB I need the details of one column,  just the column names and type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the column and type, then use DESCRIBE as you mentioned. I think you're just missing "table" after describe.

```
%sql
describe table database_name.table_name
```